# Package naming uniqueness for applications?

Tags: android

When creating an android app, we need to supply a package name in the manifest.

```
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.me.foo">
```

I believe this uniquely identifies an application, such that we can't upload an app to marketplace if another app already exists with the same package name.

Is it possible to extend a package name though without collision? For example:

```
package="com.me.foo"
package="com.me.foo.grok"
```

Will the second application be accepted by the marketplace, even though it's a substring of the first package name?

Thanks

Comment: I'd like as well to clear explanation about the package name conflicts on the market and the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this works completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I would expect to be able to do this, otherwise it would be ridiculously easy to block companies, for example by creating com.microsoft, com.google, com, etc.